# div is showing twice on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this code:

```js
    function swap(id1, id2, id3, id4) {
    $("#" + id1).fadeOut(500);
    $("#" + id2).fadeOut(500);
    $("#" + id3).fadeOut(500, function () {

        document.getElementById(id1).src = document.getElementById(id2).src;


        document.getElementById(id3).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id4).innerHTML;
    });
    $("#" + id1).fadeIn(500);
    $("#" + id2).fadeIn(500);
    $("#" + id3).fadeIn(500);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
    });
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="active" data-related="person1">

                        <div class="content-overlay" onclick="swap('img0', 'img1', 'desc0', 'desc1')"></div>
                        <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/eiffel-tower-wallpaper-18.jpg" id="img1" class="newsImage"/>
                        <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom" onclick="swap('img0', 'img1', 'desc0', 'desc1')">
                            <h3 class="content-title">This is a title</h3>
                            <p class="content-text">This is a short description</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>




     <div class="no-display" id="desc1">
                    <div class="gathering">
                        <span class="gatheringTitle">gathering 2017</span>
                        <div class="gatheringDate">
                            <span class="datee">Tue 7, Dec 2017</span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="gath">
                            <p class="text-justify gatheringText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                                elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                                labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                                ullamco
                                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cons. ullamco

                                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cons.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                     <a href="#" class="active" data-related="person1">

                        <div class="content-overlay" onclick="swap('img0', 'img1', 'desc0', 'desc1')"></div>
                        <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/Pattern-1920X1200-Wallpaper-Widescreen_318iyIu.jpg" id="img2" class="newsImage"/>
                        <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom" onclick="swap('img0', 'img2', 'desc0', 'desc2')">
                            <h3 class="content-title">This is a title</h3>
                            <p class="content-text">This is a short description</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

              </div>
                        <div class="no-display" id="desc2">
                            <div class="gathering">
                                <span class="gatheringTitle">gathering 2017</span>
                                <div class="gatheringDate">
                                    <span class="datee">Tue 8, Dec 2017</span>

                                </div>
                                <div class="gath">
                                    <p class="text-justify gatheringText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                        adipiscing
                                        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                                        exercitation
                                        ullamco
                                        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cons.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </li>
```

on click i need to change the image to another image so i did this using javascript also the div that contains the description and this how i did it but still not working

when i click on it the image change but on inspect it shows with `div class=""gathering` twice with tab-index value i just want to remove it and show it one time... anu idea? thx in advance

Comment: can you transform your code into a working snippet ? and use absolute path for images.

Comment: Did you make your divs with ids not displaying at load ?

Comment: yes only on click the divs are showing

Comment: You are showing it twice as you are replacing the html in id3 with your html in id4 so you now have 2 divs with the same html in it, surely if you just want one div, then just fade one in and one out rather than moving the html

Answer (score 0):

When calling swap() you specify

> onclick="swap('img0', 'img1', 'desc0', 'desc1')"

you use

> 'desc0', 'desc1'

while html has

> id="desc1" and id="desc2"

Not sure if this is the reason for your issue, but a snippet attached would be great advantage :) Hope this was helpful